# Getting error 403 in cosmosdb emulator "Database Account localhost does not exist"

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Hi I started using the cosomos emulator getting this error quite often please help me how to fix this. [image]

Comment: Could you please check if you are using the latest version? You can get it from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator-release-notes  If it still doesn't resolve the problem, troubleshooting steps are here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21#troubleshooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this after upgrading the emulator. Resetting the data resolved it after also reinstalling:

> If you installed a new version of the emulator and are experiencing
> errors, ensure you reset your data. You can reset your data by
> right-clicking the Azure Cosmos Emulator icon on the system tray, and
> then clicking Reset Data

This causes the data to be lost, so always back up before upgrading the emulator.